# How can I filter data in different types defined below?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here is how data looks like:

First line is the header.

This is data is formed using outer join on LI and RI.

```
LP LO LI RI RO RP
P1 O1 I1
         I2 Q1 R1
P2 O2 I3 I3 Q2 R2
P3 O3 I4
P3 O4 I5
P4 O5 I6
P4 O5 I7
         I8 Q3 R3
         I9 Q4 R3
         I10 Q5 R4
         I11 Q5 R4
P5 O5 I12 I12 Q5 R5
P5 O5 I13 I13 Q5 R5
P5 O6 I14 I14 Q5 R5
P5 O6 I15 I15 Q6 R5
P6 O7 I16 I16 Q7 R6
P6 O7 I17 I17 Q7 R6
P6 O8 I18 I18 Q8 R6
P6 O8 I19 I19 Q8 R6
P6 O8 I20 
P7 O9 I21 I21 Q9 R7
P7 O9 I22 I22 Q9 R7
P7 O10 I23 I23 Q10 R7
P7 O10 I24 I24 Q10 R7
           I25 Q10 R7
```

Final Data should look like this:

Match Data

```
LP LO LI RI RO RP
P2 O2 I3 I3 Q2 R2
```

No Match L

```
LP LO LI RI RO RP
P1 O1 I1
P3 O3 I4
P3 O4 I5
P4 O5 I6
P4 O5 I7
```

No Match R

```
LP LO LI RI RO RP
         I2 Q1 R1
         I8 Q3 R3
         I9 Q4 R3
         I10 Q5 R4
         I11 Q5 R4
```

Partial Match Scenario 1:

```
LP LO LI RI RO RP
P6 O7 I16 I16 Q7 R6
P6 O7 I17 I17 Q7 R6
P6 O8 I18 I18 Q8 R6
P6 O8 I19 I19 Q8 R6
P6 O8 I20
```

Partial Match Scenario 2:

```
LP LO LI RI RO RP
P7 O9 I21 I21 Q9 R7
P7 O9 I22 I22 Q9 R7
P7 O10 I23 I23 Q10 R7
P7 O10 I24 I24 Q10 R7
           I25 Q10 R7
```

Partial Match Scenario 2:

```
LP LO LI RI RO RP
P5 O5 I12 I12 Q5 R5
P5 O5 I13 I13 Q5 R5
P5 O6 I14 I14 Q5 R5
P5 O6 I15 I15 Q6 R5
```

Comment: Can you explain more `Partial match` vs `Match` ? Why is not partial match e.g. 2 and 3rd row?

Answer (score 0):

The logic on the partial matches in unclear, but you can easily group the successive rows by Left/Right/Match pattern based on the L/R columns using:

```
L = df.filter(like='L').isna().all(axis=1)
R = df.filter(like='R').isna().all(axis=1)
match = ~(L|R)

group = pd.Series(np.select([match, L, R], ['match', 'L', 'R']), index=df.index)

out = [(k, g) for (k, _), g in df.groupby([group, group.ne(group.shift()).cumsum()], sort=False)]
```

Output:

```
[('R',
     LP  LO  LI    RI    RO    RP
  0  P1  O1  I1  None  None  None),
 ('L',
       LP    LO    LI  RI  RO  RP
  1  None  None  None  I2  Q1  R1),
 ('match',
     LP  LO  LI  RI  RO  RP
  2  P2  O2  I3  I3  Q2  R2),
 ('R',
     LP  LO  LI    RI    RO    RP
  3  P3  O3  I4  None  None  None
  4  P3  O4  I5  None  None  None
  5  P4  O5  I6  None  None  None
  6  P4  O5  I7  None  None  None),
 ('L',
        LP    LO    LI   RI  RO  RP
  7   None  None  None   I8  Q3  R3
  8   None  None  None   I9  Q4  R3
  9   None  None  None  I10  Q5  R4
  10  None  None  None  I11  Q5  R4),
 ('match',
      LP  LO   LI   RI  RO  RP
  11  P5  O5  I12  I12  Q5  R5
  12  P5  O5  I13  I13  Q5  R5
  13  P5  O6  I14  I14  Q5  R5
  14  P5  O6  I15  I15  Q6  R5
  15  P6  O7  I16  I16  Q7  R6
  16  P6  O7  I17  I17  Q7  R6
  17  P6  O8  I18  I18  Q8  R6
  18  P6  O8  I19  I19  Q8  R6),
 ('R',
      LP  LO   LI    RI    RO    RP
  19  P6  O8  I20  None  None  None),
 ('match',
      LP   LO   LI   RI   RO  RP
  20  P7   O9  I21  I21   Q9  R7
  21  P7   O9  I22  I22   Q9  R7
  22  P7  O10  I23  I23  Q10  R7
  23  P7  O10  I24  I24  Q10  R7),
 ('L',
        LP    LO    LI   RI   RO  RP
  24  None  None  None  I25  Q10  R7)]
```

If you want to group the L/R/match in a dictionary:

```
out = {}

for (k, _), g in df.groupby([group, group.ne(group.shift()).cumsum()], sort=False):
    out.setdefault(k, []).append(g)
```